# how to start mariadb while running unit test

Tags: mariadb

ch.vorburger.exec.ManagedProcessException: An error occurred while starting the database

```
at ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.DB.start(DB.java:139)
at io.mifos.core.test.fixture.mariadb.MariaDBInitializer.startEmbeddedMariaDB(MariaDBInitializer.java:82)
at io.mifos.core.test.fixture.mariadb.MariaDBInitializer.setup(MariaDBInitializer.java:67)
at io.mifos.core.test.fixture.mariadb.MariaDBInitializer.initialize(MariaDBInitializer.java:42)
at io.mifos.core.test.fixture.DataStoreTenantInitializer.before(DataStoreTenantInitializer.java:30)
at org.junit.rules.RunExternalResourceOnce.before(RunExternalResourceOnce.java:51)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: ch.vorburger.exec.ManagedProcessException: Asked to wait for "mysqld: ready for connections." from Program [/tmp/MariaDB4j/base/bin/mysqld, --no-defaults, --console, --skip-grant-tables, --max_allowed_packet=64M, --basedir=/tmp/MariaDB4j/base, --datadir=/tmp/MariaDB4j/data/3306, --port=3306, --socket=/tmp/MariaDB4j.3306.sock] (in working directory /tmp/MariaDB4j/base), but it already exited! (without that message in console), last 100 lines of console:
210612 11:52:11 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
210612 11:52:11 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
210612 11:52:11 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
210612 11:52:11 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
210612 11:52:11 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
210612 11:52:11 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
210612 11:52:11  InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
210612 11:52:11  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
210612 11:52:11  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
210612 11:52:11  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
210612 11:52:12 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.33a-MariaDB-31.1 started; log sequence number 0
210612 11:52:12 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
210612 11:52:12 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
210612 11:52:12 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 98: Address already in use
210612 11:52:12 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
210612 11:52:12 [ERROR] Aborting

210612 11:52:12  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
210612 11:52:13  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1597945
210612 11:52:13 [Note] /tmp/MariaDB4j/base/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

at ch.vorburger.exec.ManagedProcess.startAndWaitForConsoleMessageMaxMs(ManagedProcess.java:248)
at ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.DB.start(DB.java:135)
... 15 more
```

Comment: it seems you have already a mysql/mariadb server running.

Comment: @nbk i have it running but my app does not connect to it ,,, when i try to run i receive errors showing theres problems starting it

Comment: then you must check the error of the other instance, else you have to give thesecond one anpother port like 3307 and connect to that

Comment: @nbk i gave it another port , but i got same issues, several things but same errors , i have been on this since 2days ago

Comment: iz is unclear which server you changed teh port, deinstall the secnd and post the log from the first, all other things get confusing